# Stripe popup showing wrong currency

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I've successfully setup Stripe checkout using noodliopay example ([here](https://github.com/noodlio/noodlio-pay-ionic-example/tree/master/example-checkout)) using ionic framework and angularJS. I've set the currency to pounds on charging the amount, but the popup button is still showing the dollar symbol. Below is a code snippet from factory

```
self.chargeUser = function(stripeToken, ProductMeta) {
    var qCharge = $q.defer();
    var chargeUrl = NOODLIO_PAY_API_URL + "/charge/token";

    var param = {
        source: stripeToken,
        amount: Math.floor(ProductMeta.priceGBP*100), // amount in penny
        currency: "gbp",
        description: "",
        stripe_account: STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID,
        test: true
    };

    $http.post(NOODLIO_PAY_API_URL + "/charge/token", param)
    .success(
        function(StripeInvoiceData){
            qCharge.resolve(StripeInvoiceData);
        }
    )
    .error(
        function(error){
            console.log(error)
            qCharge.reject(error);
        }
    );
    return qCharge.promise;
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?Is there any way to change the currency symbol?

Comment: post your popup code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For payment through Stripe there are two steps:

1. Get Stripe token
2. Charge the card

Earlier, I was adding the currency key on charging the card as seen in the example. But, when I added currency on getting stripe token, the issue is solved.

Thanks